# Next.js using revalidate vs static generation and client side fetching on an individual product page

Tags: next.js

I have an e-commerce website and I am trying to figure out how best to deal with the individual product pages. I would like as much static generation as possible for the product, and I know that I can use static generation for most of the page, but the part that concerns me is the user having up to date knowledge of whether the product is in stock.

I know that I can use revalidate to ensure that the product information is up to date, and likely I would set that to around 24 hours as these rarely change, but I wouldn't want to set it to be just one minute when I only really care about the stock information being that up to date.

I feel like the best way to deal with this would be by using a combination of static generation and client side fetching. I would serve all the product info using static generation except for the stock which I could fetch client side. I could also use revalidate on a 24 hour basis to make sure the rest of the product data is up to date. But the in stock would be checked fresh every time the page is accessed.

I used [this resource](https://vercel.com/blog/nextjs-server-side-rendering-vs-static-generation) to understand better what to do, but it says on an individual product page I should be using revalidate every minute, but that would be too often I think because we don't update that often, or have so many customers looking at a product every minute that we would get any benefit.

Has anyone played around with this before or know what the best practices might be?

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on the business requirements. Based on the information you provided, 24 hrs revalidation with stock information rarely changes, I can think of couple of approaches that make sense:

**Use static page with the client-side fetch**

You can use statically generated pages for the product details page with 24hr revalidation time. On the client-side, we can fetch the stock information. If you have some sort of cache on the backend for the stock information, the operation should be pretty cheap.

**Use static page without the client-side fetch**

Based on the number of products you carry, it might make sense to shorter the revalidation time. I'm talking about 10-30 minutes.

If you would like to optimize it further you can use your analytic data to determine products that frequently visited by the users and only generated those pages during build time. For other pages, you can use the fallback options. This approach should allow you to use fewer resources on your server while providing almost up-to-date stock information. There is no additional client-side fetching to complicate the source code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out both options and see what works!